# Check if an item is not selected from a dropdown

Tags: javascript

I have a dropdown list that is generating dynamically using PHP. Its rendered HTML is something similar to below markup -

```
<select size="8" id="email" name="email">
    <option value="6" data-userId="uid6">kamala@gmail.com</option>
    <option value="8" data-userId="uid8">tk@g.com</option>
    <option value="3" data-userId="uid3">myexample.com</option>
    <option value="7" data-userId="uid7">samadhi@gmail.com</option>
    <option value="2" data-userId="uid2">facebook.com</option>
    <option value="4" data-userId="uid4">lankainstitute.com</option>
</select>
```

Using this markup, just I want to check whether item is selected or not using JavaScript. If it is not selected an item, then I need to get an alert message.

I tried it something like this. But I can not get it to work.

JavaScript -

```
var email = document.getElementById("email");
var selectedValue = email.options[email.selectedIndex].value;

if (selectedValue == '') {
    alert("Please select a email");
}
```

Hope somebody may help me out. 
Thank you.

Comment: Which event you use to get selected item. Option changed or ?

Comment: What should `selectedValue` equal when successful?

Comment: @qamar, I am using onClick()

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara, It would be equal to any value of my above markup

Comment: @user3733831 So, `6`, `8`, etc?

Comment: What you are doing wrong is is doing email.options[index]; what yo need to do is email.selectedIndex instead

Comment: @qamar Actually I want to check an email is not select when the form is submitting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should listen to the `change` event of the select element and then parse the value of the selected option as an integer (`parseInt(email.options[email.selectedIndex].value, 10)`):

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/wbox6khc/)

```
var email = document.getElementById("email");

email.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    var selectedValue = parseInt(email.options[email.selectedIndex].value, 10);

    if (selectedValue === 7) {
        alert("Please select a email");
    }
});
```

```js
var email = document.getElementById("email");

email.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
    var selectedValue = parseInt(email.options[email.selectedIndex].value, 10);

    if (selectedValue === 7) {
        alert("Please select a email");
    }
});
```

```html
<select size="8" id="email" name="email">
    <option value="6" data-userId="uid6">kamala@gmail.com</option>
    <option value="8" data-userId="uid8">tk@g.com</option>
    <option value="3" data-userId="uid3">myexample.com</option>
    <option value="7" data-userId="uid7">samadhi@gmail.com</option>
    <option value="2" data-userId="uid2">facebook.com</option>
    <option value="4" data-userId="uid4">lankainstitute.com</option>
</select>
```

---

... since you're validating whether an option is selected, you would use something more along these lines:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/56ox1oxg/)

```
var email = document.getElementById("email"),
    validationButton = document.getElementById('validationButton');

validationButton.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    var selectedValue = email.options[email.selectedIndex] ? email.options[email.selectedIndex].value : null;

    if (!selectedValue) {
        alert("Please select a email");
    }
});
```

```js
var email = document.getElementById("email"),
    validationButton = document.getElementById('validationButton');

validationButton.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    var selectedValue = email.options[email.selectedIndex] ? email.options[email.selectedIndex].value : null;

    if (!selectedValue) {
        alert("Please select a email");
    }
});
```

```html
<select size="8" id="email" name="email">
    <option value="6" data-userId="uid6">kamala@gmail.com</option>
    <option value="8" data-userId="uid8">tk@g.com</option>
    <option value="3" data-userId="uid3">myexample.com</option>
    <option value="7" data-userId="uid7">samadhi@gmail.com</option>
    <option value="2" data-userId="uid2">facebook.com</option>
    <option value="4" data-userId="uid4">lankainstitute.com</option>
</select>

<button id="validationButton">Check if selected</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I want to check an item is not select when the form is submitting.

Comment: @user3733831 My bad.. something along these lines, then? http://jsfiddle.net/3j481bgr/ .. as an alternative to listening to the click event, you could also listen to the `submit` event of the form too and place your logic there.

Comment: Given that *this* within the listener is the element, then if `this.selectedIndex == -1` returns true then there is no option selected. Note that some browsers will select the first option by default.

Comment: Yes. This was what I actually needed. Thank you so much